# Selenium wait until combobox contents change

Tags: selenium, combobox, wait

I want to wait until a combobox contents change before getting the contents of that box. I don't think an implicit wait will work here as the element already exists on the page.

I'm not searching for a particular value in this combobox. I have another combobox that is populated by values and depending on what is chosen from this combobox affects the one I'm trying to wait for. There is a lag populating due to access to a database.

Sometimes this combobox may not change it's contents also.

Any suggestions appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First and simple idea is to create loop which will verify value in your comboBox until it will not changed to another one, then return back. If time of waiting is too long, then throw exception or smth like this.

Comment: Thanks Andrey for the quick response. I will try this.